# Kubernetes yaml files and Docker-compose files? Hyperledger and Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, hyperledger

I'm trying to launch Hyperledger on a Kubernetes cluster, but my first questions aren't related to Hyperledger specifically.
I'm fairly new to all of these Themes so I've got some basic questions. I'd be happy if even one of those questions could be answered.

I'know docker-compose uses .yml files. However (and I don't know if this is Hyperledger specific maybe) I keep seeing docker-compose files that are .yaml which I thought were the ones used in Kubernetes.

1 But you can't use them for Kubernetes, right? You need to use Kompose for them to be useable in Kubernetes. Does that mean yaml files are kind of "backwards compatible" that enables you to write the same as in a yml file?

(This is more about Hyperledger)
Kubernetes is getting REALLY big right now as far as I know.

2. So how come there aren't any official sample Repositories (or at all for that matter) for Hyperledger that you can use in Kubernetes?
   I haven't seen anything that would describe launching a simple Blockchain, like first-network, local on something like the Minikube.

2.1. The transition isn't SO trivial you dont need those right?
Or is a translating the frabric-samples like first-network 1 to 1 not doable?

The biggest Hyperledger on Kubernetes thing I've seen was from AidTech and they seemed Helm Charts. Or they created nephos which seems to just automate everything, which is a little bit too intransparent for me. I'd like to understand the process behind it a bit better to know how Hyperledger functions on Kubernetes.

3 Does that mean Helm Charts are the way to go? They still need to do a bunch of works for the credentials.

3.1. Is using yaml files created from the original docker-compose files that much worse? Would that mean having to learn how to write yamls and how Hyperledger works down to the smallest detail?

I'm just a bit surprised that even though Kubernetes is becoming so huge that there is nothing in depth coming from Hyperledger. Are these two may be too different so far that they should be kept separate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. taken from [official YAML site](https://yaml.org/)

   > YAML is a human friendly data serialization standard for all
   >   programming languages.

   Docker-compose and Kubernetes are container orchestrations tools and both utilize YAML as configuration files.
2. I found an example on setting up a Hyperledger development environment on Kubernetes [Medium article](https://medium.com/kokster/set-up-a-hyperledger-fabric-development-environment-on-kubernetes-6428c63e018b)
3. Helm is widely used in the Kubernetes community and there is ongoing development. I think it's just a matter of time when Helm charts are popping up for Hyperledger projects.

3.1 There is nothing wrong using Docker-compose instead of Kubernetes for local development. If you want to properly use both you should learn how to write YAML.
If you want to setup a Hyperledger project with container orchestration like Kubernetes or Docker-compose you should have indepth knowledge of the Hyperledger project as you need to understand how the components interact with each other.